# Build a character counting function

Tags: javascript, html

I need to build a small application that can take a user input and return a list of letters and number of times of occurrence of the word,
for example, user input: Hello.
Outout should be:

h: 1
e: 1
l: 2
o: 1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title>Letter Counter</title>
</head>
<body>

  <form id="word-form">
    <input type="text" id="word-input" value="hello">
    <button>Count</button>
  </form>

  <ul id="letter-list">
    <li>h: 1</li>
    <li>e: 1</li>
    <li>l: 2</li>
    <li>o: 1</li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where's the Javascript? Generally, when you have a programming problem you need to solve, the first step is to make an attempt to try to solve it

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use an Object

```js
var str = 'Hello'
var obj = {};
str.split('').forEach(function(e) {
obj.hasOwnProperty(e)?obj[e] = ++obj[e]:obj[e] = 1
})
console.log(obj)
```